# Down sampling point clouds with open3d

Tags: python, point-clouds, voxel, downsampling

I'm using the python bindings of [open3d](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/) to down sample a point cloud. The library offers two methods to do so using voxels: [voxel_down_sample](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.geometry.voxel_down_sample.html) and [voxel_down_sample_with_trace](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.geometry.voxel_down_sample_and_trace.html)

While the first returns only a down sampled point cloud, the latter returns a tuple of the down sampled point cloud and a matrix.

Per the documentation, the matrix is supposed to be a mapping between points from the original point cloud to down sampled one. However, the matrices I get are always of size `n-by-8`, with `n`being the number of points in the down sampled version. 
My question is: how do I interpret that matrix in order to retrieve the mapping between the original and down sampled point clouds?